# About SAS macro——how to use abs()/std()

Tags: sas

I write a macro sentence in SAS :

```
%macro loop;
%let sigmav=0.1;
.....
%let sigmav_new=std(V);
%if abs(%eval(&sigmav-&sigmav_new))<0.001 %then %do;
......
%mend;
```

But there are always errors of abs( ) and std( ). So I wonder whether there are special rules to express the function of abs() and std() in a macro. Hope for your help!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to call a SAS function in a macro (and outside of a data step), you need to enclose it in [%sysfunc()](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514sysfunc.htm).

Comment: In addition, you'll need to replace %eval with %sysevalf since the numbers are not integers.